# UITextView on Catalyst with Long text, invisible text ranges when scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, mac-catalyst

I have an issue with Catalyst. I'm trying to display a long text in a UITextView, and on iOS everything works well, no issues.

On Mac (with Catalyst) however, when I scroll the textview, some parts disappear. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

I have tried calling setNeedsLayout/Display/layoutIfNeeded on the textview when scrolling but no luck. The only thing that "worked" is to remove the textview from the view hierarchy and readd it to the container view on scroll finished. Still not ideal, as you lose selection when you want to select some text and scroll. (When I save the selection and re-apply it, then the blue highlight is invisible)

Using a UILabel in a scrollview could work, but then you lose all user interactions (no editing/selecting text)

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Or I should just wait for Apple to fix this.

See the video/gif of the original issue:

[image]

Comment: Created an extension that can solve it for me (call in scrollviewdidscroll)
```extension UITextView {
    // In case of long texts on Catalyst, call this on scrollviewdidscroll on the textview
    func disableTiling() {
        if #available(iOS 13.1.3, *){
            guard
                DeviceUtility.isMac,
                self.responds(to: NSSelectorFromString("_canvasView")),
                let textCanvas = self.value(forKey: "_canvasView") as? UIView
                else {return}
            textCanvas.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, size: self.contentSize)
        }
    }
}```